# How to verify that this series converges for any $a$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have known that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin n \alpha}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ converges for any `α` (real number).

```
SumConvergence[Sin[n*a]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n], n, 
 Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals]
SumConvergence[Sin[n*2]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n], n]
```

But the above code can not solve this problem, especially the conclusion that the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin n \alpha}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$ converges for any `α`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This series diverges for any real `a` because  $$ \frac{\sin n \alpha}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\approx -\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you, but why can't the following code return True:`SumConvergence[Sin[n*2]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n], n]`.

Comment: Sorry, `SumConvergence[Sin[n*2]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n], n]` returns the input in version 12.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This series diverges for any real `a` because  $$ \frac{\sin n \alpha}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\approx -\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$$ as $n \to \infty$ and Mathematica shows it through `SumConvergence[Sin[n*a]/n^2, n, Assumptions -> a ∈ Reals]` which produces `True` and `SumConvergence[-1/Sqrt[n], n]` which produces `False`.

Comment: But why can't MMA find this limit:`SumConvergence[Sin[n*2]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n], n]`?

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'd like to know how you determined $ \frac{\sin n \alpha}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\approx -\frac 1 {\sqrt n}$ as $n \to \infty$. I got a confused result by following the method: `Series[Sin[n*a]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n], {n, Infinity, -4}] // FullSimplify`.

Comment: `Limit[(Sin[n*a]/n^2 - 1/Sqrt[n])/(-1/Sqrt[n]), n -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]` performs `1`.